# Is it possible to collapse custom regions in the middle of lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VS Code support create custom folding regions in the middle of lines?

I have variables storing pictures in a format similar to `base64`, they are very large strings, my goal is to fold the not important part, leaving only some important things visible:

*Example*:

```
picture1 ="|<test1>ron[189,278,461,30]*172$461.0000000000000000000000zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzU00000000000000000000000000000000000000TzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzU"

picture2 ="|<test2>dkc[114,100,136,134]*136$136.zzzzzkM00Dzzzk007zzzXzzzzzzw0000Tzzy0007zzy7zzzzzzU0000zzzU000Dzzsm0B8Ty0000000003zzzzz8Ds04ETk000000000TzzzzykUzWV3z0000000003zzzzzxW03vxTw000040000TzzzzzrE0Dyzjk0400M0003zzzzzzz03ysAz00Ts1k001Dzzzzzzw0zvU3w0zzk7U00NzzzzzzXk/zc"

picture3 ="|<test3>zms[650,114,72,48]*180$72.kzz000000000Uzy0000000000zw000000z000000CTU000000000Czk000000000Szk000010000zzk000000001zzk000000003zzk000A00007xzk000C0000Dzzk0008k000Tzzk00080000Tzzk000E3000TzzU00003U"
```

Then after folding it would look like this:

```
picture1 ="|<test1>ron[189,278,461,30]*172..." 

picture2 ="|<test2>dkc[114,100,136,134]*136..."

picture3 ="|<test3>zms[650,114,72,48]*180...."
```

Where `...` is the part of the string that got folded.

My idea was to create a folding rule using regex or something similar

Star region: `$`
End region: `"`

I have found this extension: [maptz.regionfolder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder), but looks like it doesn't support single line folding.

I have tested it with, `settings.json`:

```
"maptz.regionfolder": {
    "[txt]": {    
        "foldStartRegex": "\\$.*",         
        "foldEndRegex": "\"",         
        "disableFolding": false //Turn off #region folding for this language
    }
},
```

[image: maptz]

As seen in the gif, it works as long the string is multi-line, however when i return it to a single line, it doesnt.

My language doesnt support breaking strings into multiple lines.

Does VS Code have built-in support for this? or someone know any other way I could achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this question [avoid ellipsis in Html tags (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75575233/avoid-ellipsis-in-html-tags-vscode) I see there is an extension that could work for you: [Inline fold](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold).  First a demo:

[image: Inline fold extension demo]

I used these settings (in `settings.json`):

```
"inlineFold.unfoldedOpacity": 0.6,
"inlineFold.maskChar": "…",
"inlineFold.maskColor": "#fff",      // change to match your text color if you like
"inlineFold.supportedLanguages": [   // add your languageID here
  "javascriptreact",
  "typescriptreact",
  "plaintext"
],
"inlineFold.unfoldOnLineSelect": true,

// to make a language-specific setting use something like this:

"[plaintext]": {          // use your languageID here
      // note that many backslashes in JSON need to be escaped themselves
  "inlineFold.regex": "(?<=\"|<.*>.*\\[[\\d,]+\\]\\*\\d\\d\\d)(\\$.*)\"$",
  "inlineFold.regexFlags": "gm",
  "inlineFold.regexGroup": "1",  // takes a string, not a number as the README examples show
  "inlineFold.autoFold": false,
}
```

I didn't know your language so I just used a `plaintext` `.txt` file for the demo and languageID.

I also made this keybinding (in `keybindings.json` or through the Keyboard Shortcuts editor):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+/",             // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "inlineFold.toggle"   // look for this in the Keyboard Shortcuts
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This feature is currently not supported. There's a feature-request issue ticket tracking it on VS Code's GitHub repo: [Support folding ranges inside a line #50840](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50840). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

For now, you can see if the [`moalamri.inline-fold`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold) extension suits your use-case <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.