# Why are my HTML class attributes collapsed inline into three dots?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[image]

I can't see the content of HTML tags until I hover over the ellipsis (three dots), how can I get rid of this?!

The ellipses go away when I disable all extensions.

Comment: First see if that still happens with all extensions disabled: Reload with all extensions disabled.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a list of your installed extensions, which you can get by running `code --list-extensions`

Comment: @Mark is not happened when disabling all extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour of attributes being collapsed into three dots is caused by the `moalamri.inline-fold` VS Code extension. You can find its Visual Studio Marketplace page [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold), and its source code [here](https://github.com/moalamri/vscode-inline-fold).

An excerpt from its readme:

> VS Code Inline Fold extension mimics VS Code's [folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding) experience for inline code.
> This is especially useful when working with frameworks like Tailwind CSS which use lots of utility classes that often disfigure code visual structure. You can expand the folds by clicking on them. You can also configure the extension to target specific attributes in your markup.
> The characters used as a mask can be configured in the settings and you can update the regex expression to match any code pattern you want.
> The extension also enables folding of attribute values within HTML/JSX tags. It makes your code tidy and easier to navigate.

There's another extension which can have a similar effect: [`stivo.tailwind-fold`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stivo.tailwind-fold).

It's useful to use [VS Code's extension bisect feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to find out what extension is causing certain behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

the case of this ellipsis is the [Inline fold extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=moalamri.inline-fold)

[image: Inline fold extension]

Comment: Can you replace the photo with a link to the extension? Or leave it and add a link?