# how to configure the display of large links in the a tag in vs code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, hyperlink

I ran into a problem that I don’t really like the display of large links in vs code.

For example,
`<a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/170784375/Landing-page-for-the-corgi-nursery?tracking_source=search_projects%7Ccorgi+landing" class="portfolio-link">Design</a>`

How can I set the links to display something like this or something shorter?
`<a href="https://www.behance.net/..." class="portfolio-link">Design</a>`

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72244103/11107541 ?