# How to create a VS Code extension to toggle visibility of some text via command or view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have a custom script file format (essentially a glorified text format) for which we have already developed a syntax highlighting extension. A language server is also in development.

I would like to display some portion of a script line (or an entire script line) in one editor view, and have it be invisible in others. I'm not adverse to having separate view panel for this, or using a command toggle it.

What would be the best way to accomplish that? I'm new to VS Code extensions, so I am not sure how to even start without flailing around for a couple of months. :)

A bit more background. The script contains display strings that get placed into a Unity string table in an external process. That requires a unique identifier (string) associated with each line of display text. I'd like to hide that identifier in the script writer view so it isn't cluttered, but show it in developer view for tracking purposes.

Thanks!

I'm new to VS Code extensions.  I've gone through the documentation, expecting to at lease get an idea of where to start, but I'm still puzzled.

Comment: could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72244103/11107541, but I think maybe not, given that you want different behaviour for different editors of the same document. does it help you?

Comment: Actually, this could be a dupe of the link you included.  We're still in development, so I can append data in question is to the end of the line, then fold from endline -15 to endline, or whatever.